# Kibana spinning for a long time

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, kibana

We just create an ES with kibana installed. There are two indices within it. One index is just for test which has 1000 documents. I search in Kibana and it works well and returned result immediately. The other index I push real data with 40,000 documents. When I search something, kibana _source  section keep spinning for >50 minutes while the 'Document Types' section return immediately.

I used curl tool to query the second index manually and it return immediately.

I compare the mapping of these two indices and only difference is I didn't use 'store' -> true in second document for some properties(some used). Is this a possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved. The fact is I added a json document without quote. ES is smart to fix it but not in _source. However, Kibana utilize _source in the table field.

Comment: This happened to me as well. In the `_source` element some of my json elements had keys without the quotes. I needed to escape my json elements in my `curl` statement with `\"`. Afterwards everything worked.